Did anyone see actual improvement from changing postgres `BLCKSZ` from default?
Someday ago I'd experimented with different postgres builds. I was changing build configuration parameters to see the impact on queries execution times. My memory can fail me, but I think I did a script that "permuted" many postgres build options from Building and Installation with Autoconf and Make. With the various builds I did run tests that I thought would showcase a change. Schemas were synthetic and some kind of reminiscence of what I had worked on those days. One thing that did not show any difference for my test was BLCKSZ(--with-wal-blocksize=BLOCKSIZE).
Anyone know real life examples of BLCKSZ doing improvement?
More specifically, database size, schemas, queries. Anything that I can reproduce, at least
synthetically.

Hi, and welcome to dba.se! You might be interested in this.

@Vérace hi, the link is irrelevant to the question.

@Vérace hi, the link has some insights, yes. but, what concerns me is there are lots of might word involved. i myself tested for the possible. at least i want to see positive answers, like,- yes, we had seen the case.

Well, all I can say is that I've yet to see a case where advice was given that in case X, you change the BLCKSZ to Y - it doesn't appear to be an issue - this is the only time I've seen it proposed, but Craig Ringer - a big hitter in the PostgreSQL sphere - proposed a different solution - and partitioning has come a long way since version 12! Plus, the fact that Erwin Brandstetter has never done it says a lot to me (hint, check his rep. here and on SO).

@Craig Ringer's comment, below his answer, clarifies things up.

Plus, there's another reason - the vast majority of PostgreSQL instances run an 8kb block size - if you change it, people may say that this is your issue/problem - I worked on a system (IBM AIX with something like a 64 bit instance on a 32 bit AIX - obviously, the chipset was 64 bit) - something to do with fees &c... I think... false economy! Any time I asked a question on the Oracle forums, people were shaking their heads saying that even though it's possible - Why on earth are you doing this?". As the Chinese expression goes "It's the nail that sticks out that gets hammered down!".

@Vérace yeah, {fees & c} somehow always overcome {IT fellas}. the business of doing license contracts somehow always > IT fellas business. For the bright side, your Chinese saying says it all. IMHO we must show to them that the number of the nails is much larger than they suspect. this way, at least it will not be the ">^", exponentionally more, operator.

I was working for a consultancy on customer site - and I had no right/voice/input into anything - since the system had been (wrongly) set up (IMHO in a few different ways) - the lunacy of running 64bit Oracle on a 32bit OS for starters - then they were using RAID5!!! Should be RAID10 - SAME!

All penny-pinching - except what they failed to take account of was the time spent by operatives waiting for screens to refresh after the "Send" button was pushed ~ 200 users waiting for upwards of minutes over a single year is $$$! Complaints used to soar come end-of-month - we'd waste a lot of time just explaining that the system is under heavy load... short-sighted management... Hmmm... Dilbert became all the more relevant to me!

@Vérace Dilbert?! sry, explain.

@Vérace from the money point of view, you, with your wish for progress,- you are evil. the operatives, who wait for screen refresh,- they are the people who make money. we, the people who do the tools, are weak link in the customer-to-investor flow of income. if i would've been removed from the chain no one would care. the outcome of such move would've been visible much later, and on a different scale. the latter becomes irrelevant, if there is no competition and motivation to produce better tooling. as a result, whole governments turn to bananas.

@Vérace my last post is just a rant and mumbling of mine. i have no, even basic, education in the economics/management fields. and those, i think, are relevant to the topic. the "short-sighted management" should have proper knowledge of what everyone should do. of how the things should go.

@Vérace regarding those unnatural things, like 32bit RDBM on 64bit OS, and like, being a weak link in the chain(wordly explanations to the customers of why the system is too slow/unresponsive/hard to use at different levels), you shud look at a different view. money x efforts. mb your company do value you as a pile of shit? no personalities, we all been there.
